Is it possible in solidity to code in erc20Token, pre-sale and ICO all in one contract?
just started learning solidity to help my friend out. I was wondering if you could and should include all the following in one contract.

Create an ERC20 Token
Pre-sale with certain white listed wallet during a period a time
Start an ICO after the pre-sale
I might be completely wrong about this, but just trying to learn.
Thanks in advance.

If it was possible, I was thinking of using the block.timestamp to do it. Could you let me know your thoughts on this as well:)

Ethereum Stack Exchange might be a better fit for this question. Make sure to follow their guidelines. Asking for "thoughts on this" is too broad both there and here. Better is to show your attempt that goes with "I was thinking" and focus your question on what isn't working.

Yes you can,
Inherite openzeppline ERC20 token contract and build out the rest
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract YourToken is ERC20, Ownable {

    // properties
      - presaleStartDate
      - presaleEndDate
      - icoStartDate
      - icoEndDate
      - presalePrice
      - icoPrice
      - whitelistedAddresses


    constructor() ERC20("YourToken", "YRTKN") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** decimals()); 
    }

    // functions
     - whitelistAddress // use this one to set addresses
     - buyTokens // used to buy either presale or ico
     - setSaleRequirements // used to set all the above properties
     - withdrawSalesProfit // you can use this to withdraw money made from sale


}


Go on an add more functions

Also building everything in one contract isn't something I would suggest though but I hope this helps
